# MongoDB group by array subfield

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hello I am new to mongoDB, please I hope you can help me with this question.

My collection will look like this:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "5f1fd47..." },
  "email":"c@c.com",
  "materials": [
    {
       "_id": { "$oid": "5f1fda2..." },
       "title": "MDF 18mm Blanco",
       "id": "mdf18blanco",
       "thickness": "18",
       "family": "MDF",
       "color": ""
    }, ...
    //others materials with different family
  ],
}
```

I did an aggregate like this:

```
{ "$match" : { "email" : "c@c.com" } }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$materials" }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "list" : { "$push" : "$materials.family" } } }
```

and I return this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1fd47d502e00051c673dd1"), 
    "list" : [
        "MDF", 
        "MDF", 
        "MDF", 
        "Melamina", 
        "Melamina", 
        "Melamina", 
        "Melamina", 
        "MDF", 
        "Melamina", 
        "Aglomerado", 
        "Aglomerado"
    ]
}
```

but i need get this

```
 { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f1fd47d502e00051c673dd1"), 
    "list" : [
        "MDF", 
        "Melamina", 
        "Aglomerado"
    ]
}
```

I hope you understand my question and can help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) instead of `$push` in your group stage:

```
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id", "list" : { "$addToSet" : "$materials.family" } } }
```

One thing to note is that `$addToSet` does not guarantee a specific order as opposed to `$push` in case it matters to you.

Answer (score 1):

You only need change `$push` to `$addToSet`.

A set not contains repeat values so it works.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "email": "c@c.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$materials"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "list": {
        "$addToSet": "$materials.family"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2LlX48Za82e)